# Белые цвета снизу и сверху на Iphone

Tags: html, css, frontend

Учусь по не многу верстке, и когда я решил посмотреть как мой сайт будет выглядеть на телефоне, увидел белые цвета снизу и с верху:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно это изменить, но я не нашел решения. Подскажите куда двигаться и что почитать, ну или можно сразу решение :)

Comment: Так что конкретно вас беспокоит? Картинку вижу, но вы хотя бы обвели рамкой, что конкретно вас не устраивает. Потому что если это то, о чём я думаю - речь о строке с часиками и уровнем сигнала телефона сверху над свёрстанным текстом. Если так, то так выглядит браузер на вашем смартфоне. Если имелось в виду что-то ещё, то хоть объясните по-людски ))

Comment: @Quazimorda Ну я же вроде нормально объяснил, у меня есть сверху и снизу белые блоки, как вы выразились где строка с часиками и уровнем сигнала телефона, такая же ситуация была в других браузерах, допустим в хром и опера, но на других сайтах, такой ситуации нету, снизу и с верху цвет такой же как и background на сайте